# API Layer ClientId and Security style

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Im at the point where I am designing my api security and I was going with a custom attribute I don't want to use third party systems as they cost money.

I was going to use the client id and the secret id approach and I am asking is this a safe enough way to accomplish it I am interacting to my api through a database layer.

So the first thing that will be called is this bit of code which goes out to find a match against the db and then called by the controller

How should I encrypt the client id though in the database so that it cant be easy guessed.

```
public bool FindKeysByClientIdByApiKey(Guid apiKey, Guid clientId)

  {

       ApiKeys results = new ApiKeys();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))

        {

            return connection.Query<ApiKeys>($"SELECT * FROM {schemaDefination}.[ApiKeys] where ClientId= @ClientId and ApiKey=@ApiKey and isActive=1 and isDeleted!=1",

              new { ApiKey = apiKey, ClientId = clientId }).Any();

        }

  }
```

Controller Code

```
public class ApiKeysController : ControllerBase

{

    DBContext db = new DBContext();

    [HttpGet]

    public int Get(Guid ApiKey, Guid ClientdId)

    {            

        if (!db.FindKeysByClientIdByApiKey(ApiKey, ClientdId))  {

            return StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

        }else

            return StatusCodes.Status200OK;

    }

}
```

To Enable or disable this at will I am creating a custom Attribute which will have the following.

```
public async  Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)

{

        //before

        if(!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(ApiKeyHeaderName, out var potentialApiKey))

        {

            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();

            return;



        }



        // before

        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(ClientId, out var potentialClientId))

        {

            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();

            return;





        }

            var getConfigurationResult = Do Stuff here



        await next();

        //after



}
```

This should mean that I can simply call attribute on my controller would this method work ok. I presume this method will also allow me to decorate my Gets and Puts to ensure that they are also authorize what should I be returning in ApiControllers get so I can make it more generic

[Apikey]

Comment: I see a view upvotes but no suggestions on how to best encrypt the client id